# Unexpected record type (org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HyperlinkRecord)

Tags: java, excel, kotlin, apache-poi, xls

**The problem:**

I'm just trying to open it .xls file using the Apache-poi 4.1.0 library and it gives the same error as 4 years ago in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785203/poi-unexpected-record-type-org-apache-poi-hssf-record-hyperlinkrecord).

**I already tried**

to put version 3.12-3.16.

> [3.13 as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34066810/9626204)

All versions can open blank .xls and filled by myself but not this one.

This document is generated automatically and I need to make a program that accepts it.

<strike>I already made a .Net standart library C# which is work, I tried to use xamarin android it's a horror, the app weighs 50 mb vs 3 mb due to various terrible SDK link errors, but that's a different story. So I decided to do it on Kotlin.</strike>

**Code**  is from the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-4.1.0)
You can check [file on git](https://github.com/Alword/Plumber71.Toolbox/blob/master/test.xls)

```
    val inputStream = FileInputStream("./test.xls")
    val wb = HSSFWorkbook(inputStream)
```

I expect no errors while opening xls.

**Actual output is**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected record type (org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HyperlinkRecord)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.RowRecordsAggregate.<init>(RowRecordsAggregate.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.<init>(InternalSheet.java:183)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.createSheet(InternalSheet.java:122)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:354)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:400)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:381)
    at ru.plumber71.toolbox.ExcelParcerKt.main(ExcelParcer.kt:19)
    at ru.plumber71.toolbox.ExcelParcerKt.main(ExcelParcer.kt)
```

The document will not be modified in any way. If there any other libraries to just read the dataset or strings from the .xls file will be OK.

Comment: Your file is corrupt. As the error states there is a `HyperlinkRecord` at a place where it not should be. `Excel` might be tolerant enough to open that file nevertheless. But you cannot expect that `apache poi` also tries to tolerate all possible violations in file format. If I open the file using `Excel` and then re-save it, `apache poi` is able creating the `Workbook` after that.

Comment: @AxelRichter I am very glad to your comment. Thank you, it really works. But this file comes from the organization several times a day, I be wanted to automate this process. (Re-save excel file/ fix file). It is strange that the [.net library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) can open it. Which I used in another project with the same file There may be no errors because it isn't provide any formatting features. Is there anything similar for Java? I need read only it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found the problem with your `test.xls` file.

According the file format specifications, all `HyperlinkRecord`s should be together in the `Hyperlink Table`. It is contained in the `Sheet Substream` following the cell records. In your case the `HyperlinkRecord`s are between other records (between `NumberRecord`s and `LabelSSTRecord`s in that case). So I suspect it was not `Excel` what had created that `test.xls` file.

`Excel`might be tolerant enough to open that file nevertheless. But you cannot expect that `apache poi` also tries to tolerate all possible violations in file format. If you open the file using `Excel` and then re-save it, `apache poi` is able creating the `Workbook`after that.

`Apache poi` is not able repairing this as `Excel` can do. But one could read the `POIFSFileSystem` a low level way and filtering out the `HyperlinkRecord`s that are between other records. That way one could read the content using `apache poi`, of course except the hyperlinks.

Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.NameRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.NameCommentRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HyperlinkRecord;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.RecordStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFName;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

class ExcelOpenHSSF {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String fileName = "test(2).xls";

  try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
       POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(is)) {

   //find workbook directory entry
   DirectoryNode directory = fileSystem.getRoot();
   String workbookName = "";
   for(String wbName : InternalWorkbook.WORKBOOK_DIR_ENTRY_NAMES) {
    if(directory.hasEntry(wbName)) {
     workbookName = wbName;
     break;
    }
   }
   InputStream stream = directory.createDocumentInputStream(workbookName);

   //loop over all records and manipulate if needed
   List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
   RecordFactoryInputStream recStream = new RecordFactoryInputStream(stream, true);

   //here we filter out the HyperlinkRecords that are between other records (NumberRecords and LabelSSTRecords in that case)
   //System.out.println prints the problematic records
   Record record1 = null;
   Record record2 = null;
   while ((record1 = recStream.nextRecord()) != null) {
    record2 = recStream.nextRecord();
    if (!(record1 instanceof HyperlinkRecord) && (record2 instanceof HyperlinkRecord)) {
     System.out.println(record1);
     System.out.println(record2);
     records.add(record1);  
    } else if ((record1 instanceof HyperlinkRecord) && !(record2 instanceof HyperlinkRecord)) {
     System.out.println(record1);
     System.out.println(record2);
     records.add(record2);  
    } else {
     records.add(record1);
     if (record2 != null) records.add(record2);
    }
   }

   //now create the HSSFWorkbook
   //see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.java?view=markup#l322

   InternalWorkbook internalWorkbook = InternalWorkbook.createWorkbook(records);
   HSSFWorkbook wb = HSSFWorkbook.create(internalWorkbook);
   int recOffset = internalWorkbook.getNumRecords();

   Method convertLabelRecords = HSSFWorkbook.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertLabelRecords", List.class, int.class); 
   convertLabelRecords.setAccessible(true);
   convertLabelRecords.invoke(wb, records, recOffset);

   RecordStream rs = new RecordStream(records, recOffset);
   while (rs.hasNext()) {
    InternalSheet internelSheet = InternalSheet.createSheet(rs);
    Constructor constructor = HSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredConstructor(HSSFWorkbook.class, InternalSheet.class);
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    HSSFSheet hssfSheet = (HSSFSheet)constructor.newInstance(wb, internelSheet);
    Field _sheets = HSSFWorkbook.class.getDeclaredField("_sheets"); 
    _sheets.setAccessible(true);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<HSSFSheet> sheets = (ArrayList<HSSFSheet>)_sheets.get(wb);
    sheets.add(hssfSheet);
   }

   for (int i = 0 ; i < internalWorkbook.getNumNames() ; ++i){
    NameRecord nameRecord = internalWorkbook.getNameRecord(i);
    Constructor constructor = HSSFName.class.getDeclaredConstructor(HSSFWorkbook.class, NameRecord.class, NameCommentRecord.class);
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    HSSFName name = (HSSFName)constructor.newInstance(wb, nameRecord, internalWorkbook.getNameCommentRecord(nameRecord));
    Field _names = HSSFWorkbook.class.getDeclaredField("names"); 
    _names.setAccessible(true);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<HSSFName> names = (ArrayList<HSSFName>)_names.get(wb);
    names.add(name);
   }

   //now the workbook is created properly
   System.out.println(wb);

/*
   //getting the data
   DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
     System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
     System.out.print(" - ");
     String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     System.out.println(text);
    }
   }
*/

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I also tried to filter, but it did not work for a long time and decided to try another library. But now you can go back. Special thanks for the resolved issue!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open a file of this "corrupted" type by using [JExcel API](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jexcel-api-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/)

But using [poi.apache.org](https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-4.1.0) also opens the file if manually resave it using excel application. (It may not be suitable for someone)

Sorry that it was asking strange questions. Thank you all and hope that someone may find useful.

```
val inputStream = FileInputStream("./testCorrupted.xls")
val workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream)
val sheet = workbook.getSheet(0)
val cell1 = sheet.getCell(0, 0)
print(cell1.contents + ":")
```